# In Chrome new Date(string date) is working but in Firefox it is showing as Invalid Date

Tags: javascript

In Chrome new Date('8-MAY-20') is working but in Firefox it is showing as Invalid Date

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

Please suggest me how to make it to work in both browsers (Firefox & Chrome)

Comment: Use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format - `new Date('2020-05-08')`. Don't try using your favorite arbitrary date string format, because chances are browsers will treat it inconsistently.

Comment: MDN lists different working constructors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date - you can use an ISO standard String or year, month, and day as numbers.

Comment: Thank you  Lionel Rowe for your update, actually from backend we are getting format  like  '8-MAY-20' only. Is there any workaround to handle this scenario at front-end UI side itself?

Comment: @Kiran You can of course parse the date yourself and pass the individual parts into `Date.UTC`, but really you should fix your backend to deliver dates in a standard format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of parsing this format of date. Polyfills of `Date#toLocaleDateString` may be required for certain environments... or you could just hard-code `MONTHS`.

`CENTURY` is hard-coded as `21`. If any 20th-century dates may be included, you'll need additional logic to handle them. If any of those dates are < 1920 (adjust for how long this app is intended to be in use), you'll hit the [Y2K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem). For this reason, 2-digit years as a canonical date format are generally a bad idea.

```js
const MONTHS = [...new Array(12).keys()].map(n =>
    new Date(1970 /* year not important */, n, 15 /* nor the day */)
        .toLocaleDateString('en-US', { month: 'short' })
        .toUpperCase())
// ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"]

const CENTURY = 21

const dateFromServerStr = str => {
    const [d, m, y] = str.split('-')
    
    return new Date(
        (CENTURY - 1) * 100 + Number(y),
        MONTHS.indexOf(m),
        Number(d),
    )
}

console.log(dateFromServerStr('8-MAY-20').toString())
```